# URL as a concatenated string in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a custom url which is within a loop so that through each loop the produced url is different. The code looks like this:

```
@foreach (var car in Model)
        {
          <div class="container">
            @{string country = Html.DisplayFor(modelCar => car.Country).ToString()}
            @{string mapUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=150x120&key=[insertkey]&center="
+ country}
            <img src=@mapUrl />
          </div>
        }
```

The problem is the line where I define `mapUrl`renders an error. What is the problem with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are simply missing the semi columns for the variables and quotes for the image src tag.

Also i am not sure why you are calling `DisplayFor` to get the country variable name! `DisplayFor` returns an MvcHtml string and is usually used to get the encoded html markup to render to browser. Unless you have some crazy overloading of that (why would you do that on DisplayFor ? Use a simply helper method), do not misuse the `DisplayFor` helper

This should work.

```
@foreach (var car in Model)
{
    <div class="container">
     @{ var country =  car.Country; }  // i assume you just need the Country 
     @{ var mapUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=150x120&key=[insertkey]&center=" + country; } 
    <img src="@mapUrl" />
   </div>
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for car.Country